# Spring boot generic controller

Tags: java, spring-boot

Let's say that I need to manage N API like this:

http://exmple1.domain.subdomain.it 
http://exmple2.domain.subdomain.it 
...
http://exmpleN.domain.subdomain.it

Is it possible to create a single Spring Boot Controller that receives all these API? Something that match the ".domain.subdomain.it" (the part that remain fixed between all the calls).
Thanks.

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't do DNS resolution; what you're refering to (misleading domain name aside) with `exmple1.domain`, `exmple2.domain`, etc are sub-domains (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain) - in general, you need to create sub-domain records on the DNS, which point to the Spring Boot service.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring. By the time your controller is hit, the DNS name has already been resolved to an IP address.

Comment: Ok I think I understand; thanks a lot